# Can anyone provide the regular expression for this: "datetime": "2014-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",

Tags: regex, unix, datetime

I need to search for and replace this complete line in a text file.

"datetime": "2014-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",

Where the date string can vary.

Trying different regex's but to no avail.  I've tried:

"datetime": "[A-Z0-9:.]*",

Comment: "Where the date string can vary."? What does that mean? You need to be more detailed, otherwise it is only possible to capture everything w/o any format check like `"datetime": "[^"]+"`

Comment: Thanks, that regex works!  much simpler than the stuff I was messing about with.  The text is a key-value pair, and the date value could vary, eg: 2014-11-28T00:00.000Z, or could be 1996-01-01T14:35:34.223Z

Answer (score 1):

Super simple solution:

```
"datetime": "[^"]+"
```

`[^"]` means "match any character that is **not** a quotation mark and the `+` means it must match multiple of them (at least one). Note that `+` is extended regex syntax (you must use `grep -E` or `egrep`, standard `grep` may not know it; same for `sed`, use `sed -E` on command line).

Of course there is no syntax check here. That regex will also match:

```
"datetime": "banana"
```

If you need syntax verification as well, the regex would be:

```
"datetime": "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}Z"
```

`{x}` means "repeat x times" and `[0-9]` means "any digit". All other characters (`-`, `T`, `Z`) match themselves.

Some people may wonder why `[.]` near the end, well, `.` means actually any character and we don't want to match any character there but only a period. I could have written `\.` instead, but when used on the shell or within scripts, multiple backslashes may be required to get the correct escaping level (e.g. within quotes it is `\\.` and so on) and I don't like that, it's ugly and error prone. Instead I put it into a character class, because within a character class period is an ordinary character an needs no escaping.

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex like

```
^"datetime":.*$
```

may help

```
$ echo '"datetime": "2014-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",' | sed 's/^"datetime":.*$/replaced/'
replaced
```